# How to allow an apparmor profile to create a unix socket

Tags: apparmor, sockets

On Ubuntu kinetic, I get multiple DENIED operations by apparmor in /var/log/syslog such as:

```
operation="create" class="net" info="failed type and protocol match" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" comm="cupsd" family="unix" sock_type="dgram" protocol=0 requested_mask="create" denied_mask="create" addr=none
operation="create" class="net" info="failed type and protocol match" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" comm="cupsd" family="unix" sock_type="stream" protocol=0 requested_mask="create" denied_mask="create" addr=none
```

I tried to allow the creation of such a socket in **/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.cupsd** by adding:

```
  unix (create) type=dgram,
  unix (create) type=stream,
```

However, restarting the systemd apparmor and cups services does not solve the issue.

Any suggestion?

Comment: same here: `audit: type=1400 audit(1679493070.946:15840): apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" info="failed type and protocol match" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=245087 comm="cupsd" family="unix" sock_type="stream" protocol=0 requested_mask="create" denied_mask="create" addr=none`  883 messages! in bookworm sid upgrade.